# Pip: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using

Tags: python, django, pip, fatal-error

I developed a complete Django project on my system. When I try to run on another system, after activating my virtual environment "data". It shows me the path of my system (where it's developed).

```
(data) PS D:\Hafiz\Data_Collection> pip    
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
'"D:\Masters_FIT\4th\Webdatabese\Project\Data_Collection\Data\Scripts\python.exe" 
"D:\Hafiz\Data_Collection\data\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On other systems python, pip, and Django are installed with their latest versions and paths are also added.

I tried a new project there and it's working properly.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "paths are also added"? You should not add absolute paths.

Comment: I'm saying about Environment Variables...

Comment: It works fine if you type `python -m pip` ?

Comment: after activating my virtual environment, it shows my upper given error...

Answer (score 1):

1. uninstall python from your machine.
2. download python installer.
3. while intalling python click on customize insatall and tick all checkbox
   and then type command ->pip
   it will 100% work i also very frusteted with this error
   follow the step

Answer (score 1):

If you play around your folders in virtual environment by renaming/moving folders, this error will come. In my case it was showing me a path that exists in my laptop before I formatted it last year.

[(pypackages) C:\ts\SecureShield\git\UACSClient\frnod\packages\Scripts>pip install --trusted-host pypi.org nuitka Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\ts\csincs\aforgecameracapture\camera-capture-csharp\userregistration\bin\frnod\packages\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\ts\SecureShield\git\UACSClient\frnod\packages\Scripts\pip.exe" install --trusted-host pypi.org nuitka': The system cannot find the file specified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW2QB.png)

On further analysis, I found this path gets written to pip.exe when a virtual environment is created. One should not rename the folders after creating a virtual environment. i fixed this error by creating a fresh venv.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system enviropment PATH

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).